# A question about Hilbert Spaces and convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am struggling with this and could really do with some help:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{R}$, $\{v_n\}$ be a sequence of vectors in $H$, and $C$ be a convex subset of $H$ containing $\{v_n\}$. 
Now, let $v$ be a vector in $H$ and $c\in \overline{C}$ be the point minimising $\|c-v\|$. Finally, let $u= c-v$. 
 
 Show that $\forall w \in \overline{C}$, we have $$\langle w,u \rangle \geq \langle c,u \rangle,$$ and so $$\langle v_n, u \rangle \geq \langle c,u \rangle \  \ \ \ \ \forall n$$

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Write the inequality as $\langle w-c,c-v\rangle \geqslant 0$. For $0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1$, let $w_t = c + t\cdot (w-c)$. Consider $f(t) = \lVert w_t - v\rVert^2$.

Comment: Ah yes that was a part of the question I forgot to include. I'm not sure how you implement this to gain the answer.

Comment: $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ has a (global) minimum at $t = 0$. what does that say about $f'(0)$?

Comment: Well, that would mean that $f'(0)$ would have to be $0$ also, right? Then does this imply that $||w-c||=0$?

Comment: No, $f'(0)$ need not be $0$. It's only at interior points of the domain that an extremum implies a vanishing derivative. (Consider $g(t) = t$. On the domain $[0,1]$ it has a global minimum at $0$, but its derivative is $1$ everywhere.)

Comment: Then is $f'(t)= 2||w-c||$ for all $t$?

Comment: Sorry, that is incorrect.
I mean to say that does this mean $f'(0)$ is the smallest value of $f'(t)$, with $f'(t) = ||w-c|| \, ||w_t-v||$?

Comment: Write $f(t) = \langle (w_t - c) + (c-v), (w_t - c) + (c-v)\rangle$.